# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'element') in react

Tags: reactjs

i try to set data using setstate this.setState({DataArray:DataArray,countData:countData + 1 });       but it showing

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'element')
```

there is no null data in json .

```
validateData =() => {
    var DataArray = this.state.DataArray;  
    if(DataArray.length > 0)
    { 
        DataArray.shift();
        var countData = this.state.countData; 
        this.setState({DataArray:DataArray,countData:countData + 1 });   
        this.interval = setTimeout(() => {
            if(DataArray.length !== 0){  
                this.validateData();     
            } 
        }, 1000);

        if( DataArray.length === 0){  
            this.InsertData(); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear how you initialized your state. Maybe the mistake is there. Anyway, the problem is probably in this:

setState - is asynchronous. You should not rely on its result.

In order to make it reliable you should do it like this:

this.setState(newState, callbackFunction)

callbackFunction is called after the state is updated